# Implementing Avery Monarch 9416XL printer into C# project

Tags: c#, printing

has anyone had any dealings with the above mentioned printer or one like it? I have been handed the task of introducing this printer into our c# project and am not sure where to start. I have created a sample .lbl file using Averys recommended software to get all of the dimensions correct. (Nicelabel SE)
the printer is connected to the PC via Network.

here is a [Sample Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-r6oTXhFux5SFZiTTZVYVJNbjQ/view?usp=sharing) of the project that I am trying to create, I have spoken to one of the engineers at Monarch and he is helping me with creating a base file to send to the printer, and having some of the data as a variable.

ideally it would be good if I could launch a dos program which would handle this for me, but I seem to really be pulling at straws here.. I have seen the Zebra SDK, but im not sure if this printer is compatible. 
Thanks.

Comment: I can connect to the printer via RS232 if it makes the process easier..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spoken to the Guys from Avery and they built a template for me to use, and with a variable section in the code I was able to put in my own settings to get the required output. 
To send the file to the printer I was able to use the LPR Service in windows using a batch file.